# How do I type 3 "times"5 (like 3 x 5)

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I'm wondering how I can type "time". (I could omit it, but I want to emphasize that it is a product, so I want to type it out). Does anyone have a good idea?

Comment: Do you mean `$3 \times 5$` ?

Comment: `$3 \cdot 5$` is also possible.

Comment: If this is math, use `$3 \times 5$`. Otherwise, some authors prefer `3 x 5`. For example, Jost Hochuli: `@Book{Hochuli:2009, author = {Hochuli, Jost}, title = {Details in Typography}, year = {2009}, comment = {With minor corrections}, publisher = {Hyphen Press}, isbn = {978-0-907259-34-3}, }`.

Comment: @JLDiaz Thanks for your answer! This is exactly what I wanted. didn't expect that it was that simple lol

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @closevoters: Just because a question is very basic/elementary doesn't mean it's _too localized_! This is rather a dupe of our symbol question, since `\times` is on detexify.

Comment: @doncherry It can't be a duplicate as it depends on the context. See my answer. Especially art brochures seem to prefer the `x` notation, whereas math prefers `\times`. I have to agree that `x` looks better if it's not math (but I've sinned).